# Функция поиска наиболее часто встречающихся символов. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Алиса сидела со старшей сестрой на берегу и маялась: делать ей было совершенно нечего, а сидеть без дела, сами знаете, дело нелегкое; раз-другой она, правда, сунула нос в книгу, которую сестра читала, но там не оказалось ни картинок, ни стишков. "Кому нужны книжки без картинок или хоть стишков, не понимаю!" - думала Алиса.

```
    В тексте найти 3 наиболее часто встречающихся символа, вывести текст на печать, выделив эти три символа красным, синим и зеленым цветами соответственно. Пробел не учитывать.
```

Help плиззз.

```
function letterSearch(str)
{
    var alfabet = "абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюя";
    var arr = alfabet.split("");// разбиваем на отдельные буквы
    console.log(arr);
    str = str.toUpperCase(); // повышаем все буквы до строчных чтоб одинаковые были
    var str = str.replace(/\s+/gm, ''); // убираем все пробелы из строки
    let letterArr = Array.from(str);// разбили строку на массив отдельных символов
    console.log(letterArr);
    var i;
    var j;
    for (i = 0; i < arr; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < letterArr.length; j++)
```

Дальше - тупик.
Спасибо всем за помощь. буду признательна даже в большей степени за алгоритм решения задачи, хочу понять... Я - совсем начинашка, если что.

Comment: Один из вариантов - создать массив, где ключём будет символ, а значением - количество раз повторения. Дальше от 1 до длинны строки перебирать символы и если находится уже сущетсвующий символ, тогда значение инкрементируется иначе добавляется в массив ключ со значением 1. Плюс проверка не равен ли символ пробелу.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function mostUsedLetters(sourceString) {
  // фильтруем строку, оставив только буквы
  const filteredStr = sourceString.toLowerCase().replace(/[^а-яё]/g, ''); 
  // считаем в объект кол-во вхождений каждой буквы, используя ее как ключ
  const charsCount = {}; 
  for (const chr of filteredStr)
    charsCount[chr] = (charsCount[chr] || 0) + 1; 
  // преобразуем полученный объект в массив объектов
  const result = Object.keys(charsCount)
    .map(chr => ({ letter: chr, count: charsCount[chr] })); 
  // возвращаем отсортированный результат
  return result.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count); 
}

const text = 'Алиса сидела со старшей сестрой на берегу и маялась: делать ей было совершенно нечего, а сидеть без дела, сами знаете, дело нелегкое; раз-другой она, правда, сунула нос в книгу, которую сестра читала, но там не оказалось ни картинок, ни стишков. "Кому нужны книжки без картинок или хоть стишков, не понимаю!" - думала Алиса.'; 
// посчитаем буквы нашей функцией, и отрежем от результата первые 3 элемента
const top3 = mostUsedLetters(text).slice(0, 3); 
// выведем результат в консоль, красиво отформатировав
console.log(top3.map((obj, i) => `${i + 1}: буква '${obj.letter}'\n   встречается ${obj.count} раз(а)`).join('\n'));
```

---

> вывести текст на печать, выделив эти три символа красным, синим и зеленым цветами соответственно.

Это уж сделай самостоятельно.
Достаточно пройтись циклом по исходной строке еще раз, составляя новую строку с html-разметкой: проверяем текущий символ на совпадение с тремя самыми частыми (для удобства, их лучше заранее отмапить в плоский массив), и если символ совпадает, то оборачиваем его в `<span>` с классом соответствующего цвета. После завершения цикла, полученную разметку помещаем в элемент.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. А скажите пожалуйста, почему мы отрезаем от результата 3 элемента?

Comment: @Alisa, Ну наверное потому что в вопросе написано _«В тексте найти 3 наиболее часто встречающихся...»_. А для благодарностей, слева от каждого вопроса и ответа предусмотрена специальная кнопочка   :)